# How to install components in Apache Service Mix (Fuse ESB)?

Tags: middleware, soa, apache-servicemix, fuseesb

Initially some of the components are installed.

Some components we need to install like Mybatis,CXF,JAXB etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install them using the shell

```
features:install camel-mybatis
```

Comment: But Whnen I am trying to install this by shell, it shows an error of missing packages or missing manifest files in the package. How can I re-download those packages